# Alter column length of existing table with millions of rows

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to extend the column length of a VARCHAR field from 50 to 250.  There are already 1 million+ rows in the table to be altered.

Are there any risks associated with extending the field?  Is this a quick process for Sybase to carry out or is it likely to take a long time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be very quick, as you're changing only metadata.

To be 100% sure specify NULL/NOT NULL explicitly, in order to avoid issues with session default settings.